# React Testing Library can identify the disabled status of a button but not its text is related to

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

why react testing library  can't identify a disabled button text but can identify the button whether it is disabled or not when use `findByRole` query?

```
expect(
      await screen.findByRole('button', { name: /Generating Configuration/i })
    ).toBeInTheDocument();
```

the above code not work but the below one pass the tests

```
expect(
      await screen.findByRole('button', { name: /Generating Configurations/i })
    ).toBeDisabled();
```

this works

###### Button Element

```
<button
  class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root Mui-disabled"
  disabled=""
  type="button"
>
Generating Configurations

</button>
```

I'm trying to asset the button containing the text `Generating Configurations

##### AutoDeployment.test.tsx

```
import { fireEvent, getMockServer, screen, waitFor } from 'test/utils';
import { devEnv } from 'data/testData/TestComponentTestData';
import { commitHistory } from 'test/graphql/data/project.data';
import { deployViewSetup, customDeployViewSetup } from 'test/customSetup';
import { APIName } from 'test/constants';
import { onResponse, resetMockHandler } from 'test/apiServer.mock';
import { enableAutoDeployByDefault } from 'config';
import EnableAutoDeployments from './EnableAutoDeployments';

const server = getMockServer({
  apiList: [APIName.ConfigurationMgt],
  isGraphqlServerEnabled: true,
});

beforeAll(server.listen);
afterEach(() => {
  server.resetHandlers();
  resetMockHandler();
});
afterAll(() => {
  server.close();
});

describe('Deployment on commit', () => {
test('should enable and disable deployment on commit', async () => {
    deployViewSetup(
      <EnableAutoDeployments
        devEnv={devEnv}
        commitSha={commitHistory.commitHistory[0].sha}
      />
    );

    onResponse((mockedRequest, mockedResponse) => {
      const {
        request: { path, method },
      } = mockedRequest;
      if (path.includes('/configurations') && method.toLowerCase() === 'get') {
        return { jsonSchema: 'test-schema' };
      }
      return mockedResponse;
    });

    expect(screen.getByText(/Auto Deploy on Commit/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(
      await screen.findByRole('button', { name: /generating configurations/i })
    ).toBeDisabled();
    
   })
})
```

Comment: The question needs clarity, which test is working and which doesnt.

Comment: Can you please provide the message you get when the test does not pass?

Comment: `expect(
      await screen.findByRole('button', { name: /Generating Configuration/i })
    ).toBeInTheDocument(); ` 

is not working correctly but,

`expect(
      await screen.findByRole('button', { name: /Generating Configurations/i })
    ).toBeDisabled();` is working correctly

Comment: The error message received was
`expect(element).toBeInTheDocument()

    element could not be found in the document

expect(await screen.findByRole('button', { name: /Generating Configurations/i })
).toBeInTheDocument();
`

Answer (score 0):

toBeInTheDocument is not part of RTL. You need to install jest-dom to enable it.

And then import it in your test files by:

import '@testing-library/jest-dom'

Comment: jest-dom is already installed as a dependency. What I'm missing here?

Comment: have you import import '@testing-library/jest-dom' in yout App-test.js file.
if yes and still your facing the issue then requesting you to post your App-jest.js file code

Comment: update the question with the test code

Comment: you have not import import '@testing-library/jest-dom' line in App-test.js file\